# React-Native: redux-saga: Cannot access static class in selector in release mode

Tags: android, react-native, redux, crash, redux-saga

I have a react-native redux saga app, using bluetooth (react-native-ble-plx) and react-navigation. Because I'm not fond of how react-navigation works with the navigation-prop, I extracted the root-navigation to a service exactly as they suggested in the docs (see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

So far so good.

At the same time I really want to keep the redux-saga way of working, so I made selectors for fetching the current-route, navigation-parameters and the navigator, like this:

```
export const getNavigator = (state)  => {
  return NavigationService.getNavigator();
};

export const getCurrentRoute = (state) => {
  const navigator = NavigationService._navigator;
  if (isNil(navigator) || !navigator.state.nav) {
    return;
  }
  return navigator.state.nav.routes[navigator.state.nav.index] || undefined;
};
```

I have a `navigation-service`:

```
class NavigationService {

  _navigator;

  setNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    this._navigator = navigatorRef;
  }

  getNavigator() {
    return this._navigator;
  }
}

export default new NavigationService();
```

I have written this NavigationService as a static class and as just methods that are exported with a global _navigation property, exactly as in the docs of react-navigation: All of the 3 approaches give exactly the same result.

This setup works like a charm... IF the debugger is attached.

The moment I detach the debugger (logs are written to logcat), the app crashes. It first hangs on the first rule in the selector that accesses NavigationService (no matter how I write the service), and after some time (< 30 seconds) the app is killed by the OS.

The last log-statement exactly before accessing the NavigationService is written, the log-statement directly afterwards not. Then no relevant logs are printed until:

```
null 1218-2674/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.myapp.app/.MainActivity
null 1218-2674/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
null 1218-1242/? D/RestartProcessManager: increase duration : 135924 for com.myapp.app
null 1218-1785/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 2 when =1443332710 package =android operation = null listenTag =*job.delay* flags =0x0
null 26300-26300/? I/RecentsModel: onTaskStackChanged# mTaskChangeId=45
null 1218-1242/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{f0377cf u0 com.myapp.app/.MainActivity t16320 f}
null 1218-1242/? D/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: Activity is not Triggerred in full screen ApplicationInfo{b52dd87 net.oneplus.launcher}
null 26300-26300/? D/RecyclerViewWrapper: onWindowVisibilityChanged:4
null 26300-26300/? D/Launcher: onStart# hashcode: 116042472
null 1218-1242/? D/RestartProcessManager: Update Total Launch Times :net.oneplus.launcher
    sLastRunningPackage (null) : net.oneplus.launcher
null 26300-26300/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHost: setListenIfResumed# listenIfResumed: true, flag: 2
null 1218-1798/? W/InputDispatcher: channel '51ea069 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
null 1218-1798/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '51ea069 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
null 26300-26300/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHostView: updateAppWidget: com.oneplus.security
null 26300-26300/? D/LauncherAppWidgetHost: startListening# flag: 7
null 26300-26300/? D/NotificationListener: setNotificationsChangedListener# l: net.oneplus.launcher.popup.PopupDataProvider@1434aa6
null 26300-26300/? D/NotificationListener: checkPermissionGranted# grant: false
null 26300-26300/? D/WallpaperEventHandler: [onLauncherStart] mWillResetWallpaper=false
null 26300-26300/? D/Launcher: onResume# code: 10410, name: 3.4.0.190728151428.eef8c2c
null 26300-26300/? D/Launcher: onResume# hashcode: 116042472, resource folder: values-sw440dp-xxhdpi
null 26300-26300/? D/Launcher: onResume# isDragging=false
null 26300-26300/? D/Launcher: DynamicIcon doWorkspaceOrFolderIconAnimation be enter
null 26300-26300/? D/Launcher.Workspace: DynamicIcon Workspace updateCurrentPageDynamicIconState success
null 26300-27659/? D/Launcher: onResume# isInteractive=true
null 26300-26300/? D/RecyclerViewWrapper: onWindowVisibilityChanged:0
null 1218-4167/? D/ConnectivityService: ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=3304, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10420] ], android.os.BinderProxy@2feffbc)
null 1218-2830/? D/ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=3304, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10420] ] (release request)
null 1218-4167/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{51ea069 u0 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.MainActivity}
null 1218-4167/? W/InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '51ea069 com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.MainActivity (server)'
null 706-1772/? I/sensors-hal: activate:99, android.sensor.accelerometer/45 en=0
null 3157-3157/? D/PhoneSwitcherNetworkRequstListener: releaseNetworkFor NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=3304, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Unwanted:  Uid: 10420] ]
null 706-1772/? I/sensors-hal: activate:110, android.sensor.accelerometer/45 en=0 completed
null 3131-3131/? D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 1
null 1218-4158/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.myapp.app(pid 32622) has died: vis  +99TOP 
null 1218-4158/? W/ActivityManager: AMS will block com.myapp.app(com.myapp.app) autostart due to process is killed by lmk in low memory
null 634-634/? I/Zygote: Process 32622 exited due to signal (11)
```

Also my wallpaper is being reset to the default (not that relevant I guess).

Versions:

```
"react": "16.8.6"
"react-native": "0.60.5"
"react-navigation": "4.0.0"
"react-navigation-stack": "1.5.1"
"react-redux": "7.1.1"
"redux": "4.0.4"
"redux-persist": "6.0.0"
"redux-saga": "^1.0.5"
```

I'm running on android, and I tried enabling and disabling Hermes JS Engine.

I suppose this has something to do with the JS engine on the phone, since with the debugger it does work.

So my questions are:

- How come I cannot access any normal js-class, exported function, or global variable in redux-selectors?
- How come this does work when the debugger is attached?
- Is it bad practice to do anything else than store fetching in selectors?
- Is there any way to fix this?

Any insights or information about any special context selectors are running in on the phone JS engine or Hermes JS engine is more than welcome!

**Update:**

After 3 days of debugging and trying all kinds of stuff, I found the trigger of the crash: The moment the `navigatorRef` from react-navigation is in any possible way used in a saga or a selector (even just `console.log(NavigationService._navigator)`, the app crashes (only when the debugger is not attached). So for some reason that object is banned in redux-saga. Still no idea why, and still no idea why it does work with a debugger attached.